# Cannot release IUnkown object, getting error: HRESULT: "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: c++, com, directshow

I am trying to 'release' some IUnkown COM objects but I get the error:

> hr = 0x00000002 : The system cannot find the file specified.

This happens when I try to release a moniker and/or a propertybag object. I have simplified the code in order to simplify the problem. My code works up till where I call `BindToStorage` (this call returns `S_OK`) yet when I call release I get my error.

```
IEnumMoniker *pEnum;
HRESULT hr = EnumerateDevices(CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory, &pEnum);

IMoniker *pMoniker = NULL;
IPropertyBag *pPropBag = NULL;

if(pEnum->Next(1, &pMoniker, NULL) == S_OK){
    hr = pMoniker->BindToStorage(0, 0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pPropBag));
    hr = pPropBag->Release();
    hr = pMoniker->Release();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In my simplification I forgot to add the brackets. I have edited my question to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IUnknown::Release` returns outstanding reference count, not `HRESULT`. The value of two is valid and you are supposed to simply ignore it. It does not mean there there is a file error or otherwise "The system cannot find the file specified." This behavior is documented - standard COM behavior, [see MSDN for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682317%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: +1, also it's worth noting that `Release()` is declared to return `ULONG`, not `HRESULT`.